# AppRTC is showing duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apprtcdemo

I've a unique problem. I'm including the AppRTC in my project via. podfile. It is successfully getting installed and along with it libjingle_peerconnection and SocketRocket libraries are also getting installed. However when I build my project it shows duplicate symbol error for libWebRTC.a and gives the following message -->

> duplicate symbol _RTCFileName in:
>       (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(libjingle_peerconnection_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(rtc_base_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RTCLogEx in:
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(libjingle_peerconnection_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(rtc_base_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>   duplicate symbol _RTCSetMinDebugLogLevel in:
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(libjingle_peerconnection_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(rtc_base_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>   duplicate symbol __Z27RTCGetNativeLoggingSeverity18RTCLoggingSeverity in:
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(libjingle_peerconnection_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>        (My project path)/Pods/libjingle_peerconnection/libjingle_peerconnection/libWebRTC.a(rtc_base_objc.RTCLogging.o)
>   ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried everything related to this but with no success. So please help me to solve it or atleast tell why this is happening.

Comment: Did you add any file manually?

Comment: No ekta, i didn't added any file manually. All I did is to install appprtc via podfile and commands needed to install pods. what you suggest?

Comment: What might be causing this? is that library problem?

Comment: Hi Mohit , any solution you got ?.. I am having same issue.

Comment: no Buddy i haven't got solution. have you figured out something?